# Using my flask SQLAlchemy model in another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask web app, and I would like to use my model in another module (using the same database).

This other module is not a web site, but it runs in the background and does analysis of the data. I would like to keep these two separate, but how could I go about this?

Will it be better to use the regular SQLAlchemy package with this other module, and basically follow the setup of using an existing database? (I would like to run it in Docker, so running them in separate services there)

Importing the flask app into this second module seems a bit dirty, as it won't need anything related to it (routes, templates, views ..), just the db model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I faced the same problem and found it was better to define my models in a separate module using regular sqlalchemy and import them in to the flask app. This link covers using regular sqlalchemy with flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/

Comment: Alternatively, what I could think of is that you create a third service. This service will hold the DB and it will also expose an (most likely internal) API from which the two other apps can call to.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can have a look at using the SQL Alchemy directly, might be a good option. With Flask SQLAlchemy I just feel like I'm painting myself into a corner, if I add on other services and then have to have them depend on Flask.